# Prove that the length of this curve decreases as one of its parameters increases

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, inequality

The following is the problem statement of one of my assignment questions.

> Consider the $\partial_t (t,s) = K(t, s)N(t, s)$  for all $t \geq 0$, and for all $s \in [0, 1]$, where $T(t, s) = \frac{\partial_sx(t, s)}{||\partial_sx(t, s)||}, \ N(t, s) = \frac{\partial_sT(t, s)}{||\partial_sT(t, s)||}, \ K = \frac{||\partial_sT(t, s)||}{||\partial_sx(t, s)||}$ for all $t\geq0$ for all $s \in [0, 1]$, and $x: [0, \infty] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is an infinitely differentiable solution such that $||\partial_sx(t, s)||$ and $||\partial_sT(t, s)||$ are non-zero for all . Define $$L(t)=\int_0^1 ||\partial_sx(t, s)||ds \ \ \ \ \forall t \geq0$$
>   Assume that $\partial_tL_t=\int_0^1 \partial_t||\partial_sx(t,s)||ds \ \ \ \ \forall t \geq0$. 
>   Show that the length of $ \{x(t, s): s\in [0,1]\}$  decreases as t increases. 
>   Hint: $||\partial_sx)t,s)|| = \partial_sx(t, s).T(t, s)$

I think essentially, we are to prove the inequality $\partial_t L_t=\int_0^1 \partial_t ||\partial_s x(t,s)||ds < 0$, because this would show that the length L decreases with increasing t. However, I don't have a clear strategy on how to approach this. I've been thinking about whether using the mean value theorem would work as I have seen it used to prove inequalities, though I don't yet know how to apply that here. So, hints on how to approach this would be much appreciated, thanks.